# php trying to integrate n12br (new line) to my php source

Tags: php, html

I'm having problems creating a new line so whenever there is an input it automatically creates a new line.

If I'm ever to understand php I need to learn how to integrate functions better...

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php
$txt = "alertmon_user.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['field1'])) { 
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
    $txt = $_POST['field1']; 
    fwrite($fh,$txt); 
    fclose($fh); 
}
?>
```

Thank You

Comment: `"\n"` <- new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the PHP Constant PHP_EOL

ex:

```
<?php
$txt = "alertmon_user.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['field1'])) { 
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
    $txt = $_POST['field1']; 
    fwrite($fh,$txt . PHP_EOL); 
    fclose($fh); 
}
?>
```